# Improve Eclipse look and feel on Fedora

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, fedora

I am using Eclipse Neon on Fedora 24. The look and feel is not as great as Eclipse on Windows - for example, it takes a long time for the mouse pointer to become draggable when on the border of two windows. What are some potential solutions to improve this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you record a video of the slow and non-slow draggable pointer? It would help us understand the problem better.

Comment: Also: do you mean the look and feel in a _cosmetic_ sense, or entirely pragmatic, functional things like the example you give? Do you have other specific examples?

Comment: Hello, 

I'm an Eclipse SWT developer working on the U.I of Eclipse on Fedora.

There isn't a good single answer for your question, it may require some investigation.

I usually hang out on IRC: freenode#swt  as lufimtse 
Feel free to come ping me.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

- Sometimes certain plugins cause glitches. For example I know Javascript plugin interferes with C development sometimes. Try a fresh upstream Eclipse with a fresh workspace, ex try the latest 'maintenance' eclipse:
  http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/
  These often have the latest fixes.
- If you've turned on the black theame, you could try the regular white theame as currently there are some u.i issues specific to the dark theme. ex:
  499515: [Gtk3][Dark] Click on package explorer only works on second click when dark theme is enabled
  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499515
- Some Window managers (ex i3) tend to introduce visual glitches in Eclipse. Try alternative window managers or the standard 'gnome' to see if there is a difference.
- If you're running wayland, currently Eclipse is a little unstable on wayland, but port is in progress: 496923: [Wayland] Improve support for Wayland in 4.7
  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496923
- You should also consider submitting a bug with more specific details of your setup, (help -> about -> installation details -> Configuration, copy and attach). To do so, go here:
  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform
  Select "SWT" from Component.
- If all else fails, I often hang out on freenode#swt, feel free to ping me there. (lufimtse)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://coffeeorientedprogramming.com/2016/10/06/make-applications-eclipse-use-x11-backend-on-wayland-fedora-25/

and I modified my  /usr/share/applications/elipse.desktop exec parameter,  like this

**Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 eclipse**

my eclipse.desktop =>

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name= Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
**Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 eclipse**
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Encoding=UTF-8
```